# Haskell - How to infer the type of action

Tags: haskell

An example from Wikibooks (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Simple_input_and_output)

```
doGuessing num = do
   putStrLn "Enter your guess:"
   guess <- getLine
   if (read guess) < num
     then do putStrLn "Too low!"
             doGuessing num
     else if (read guess) > num
            then do putStrLn "Too high!"
                    doGuessing num
            else putStrLn "You Win!"
```

Wikibooks says 'doGuessing num' has type IO () in the outer "then" branch.

```
  do putStrLn "Too low!"
     doGuessing num
```

I don't understand why 'doGuessing num' has type IO (), and just guess this is because:

```
 1)the last "else" brance (putStrLn "You Win!") has type IO ().
 2)in Haskell, "then" branch and the "else" branch have the same type.
 3)the final action (putStrLn "You Win!") defines the type of the whole do block.
```

so 'doGuessing num' has type IO ().

I am not sure my understanding is right. Actions is new for me, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That is approximately the algorithm that Haskell uses for figuring out the types of expressions. For more detailed description of the idea you intuited, read about [Unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29#Application:_Type_inference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, all of that. In this example, there's a whole bunch of ways in which Haskell can infer the type.

(In addition to what you said: all actions in a `do` block must be *in the same monad*; the first `putStrLn "Enter your guess: "` already gives you that `doGuessing` is in the `IO` monad (i.e. `IO a` for some yet unknown `a`. The `()` yielded by the `putStrLn` is not relevant here).
The same goes for `guess <- getLine`, this is also an `IO` action.)

The great thing about a Hindley-Milner type system such as Haskell is that there is not a single “route” for how type information travels through the code. It's not that type information is in some way attached to values, like in a dynamic language. (The kind of type inference that C++ or Java uses is basically a “pre-simulation” of that dynamic-type flow.)

Rather, the compiler gathers all information it can find, anywhere, and combines it to infer the type of the whole expression. As musically_ut already remarked in the comments, this is done through [type unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29#Application:_Type_inference).